# On third page not getting next page token google place api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-places-api

On third page not getting next page token google place api?

I am using Google place text search API in my **Ruby on rails** application, everything is working fine but after third page I am not getting any next page token so for every text search I am getting only **60** result. Is I am missing something please suggest any help would be appreciable. This happen for every text.

- My request for first page :-

  ```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=#{my_key}&query=#{my_query}
  ```
- My request for other page with token:-

  ```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=#{my_key}&pagetoken=#{next_page_token}
  ```

And usually I am searching on google it show 100's of result for same place text. How can I get result more than 60.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any other way to get more than 60 results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behavior for Google's Places API, as you can only get up to 60 places, split across 3 pages (3 queries). This is why there is no `next_page_token` on the third page.

> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20
> `establishment` results per query; however, each search can return as
> many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will
> return more than 20, then the search response will include an
> additional value — `next_page_token`.

Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging).

Comment: After so much of googling I also got the same reason. But still thanks a lot for your response.